# git with symlinks on Windows

Tags: git, github, symlink

(I am using Windows at the moment with git installed and GitHub Win client)

I have forked a repo which contains config.ini

Now I need to be able to put my settings in there but still maintain it so I can contribute back.

I was thinking about a symlink using like [Git best practice for config files etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342886/git-best-practice-for-config-files-etc/9343239#9343239) however when I do all of that and then go to my GitHub Win client it was to contribute config-sample.ini as a NEW file!

Shouldn't symlink make it so that GitHub thinks the changes were in config.ini even though I made them in config-sample.ini ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Um, how on earth are you using symlinks on Windows? Windows doesn't use the same kind of symlinks that OS X and Linux uses. For example, Windows doesn't have a `ln` command available. It uses a [`mklink`](http://lifehacker.com/5496652/how-to-use-symlinks-in-windows) command instead, and even then, Windows implements symlinks differently.

Comment: git allows you to run ln, have also tried Windows mklink

Comment: You mean git bash lets you use `ln`? I suspect that the git bash version of `ln` is really just an alias for Window's `mklink`, which again, is not the same thing as a symlink is OS X and *nix systems. A symlink in a *nix system will have the path for what it refers to in a single line of plain-text. I'm not sure if Window's symlinks are the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens when I clone a repository with symlinks on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662868/what-happens-when-i-clone-a-repository-with-symlinks-on-windows)

Comment: What @Cupcake said. See [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11664305/720999) for more details. As a person keeping an eye of GfW development I might assure that the situation has not changed since then (that is, the newest GfW preview release does not have support for symlinks).

Comment: By the way, there's a [pull request](https://github.com/msysgit/git/pull/172) about adding some support for symlinks to Git -- you might be interested to follow its discussion.

Comment: Dupe or related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641864/git-bash-shell-fails-to-create-symbolic-links/40914277#40914277 => In this one there's the solution via MSYS env var.