# Github pull request pick individual changes

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request, staging

I'm working with a Firebase Cloud Functions project and it has two branches `main` for production and `development` for staging. Because production and staging are linked to different Firebase projects both branches need different config files (such as serviceAccountKey.json)

my question is:

Is possibile whenever I make a PR in Github to pick which changes need to be merged, and which to be discarded?

Because every time I merge, the production config files are overwritten by the staging ones.

I don't know if that's the proper way to manage those type of situations but in general I would like to know if such a feature is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git best practice for config files etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342886/git-best-practice-for-config-files-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `serviceAccountKey.json` in the [`.gitignore` file list](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and provide a `serviceAccountKey-template.json` for new comers.