# Best workflow to release updated config files without breaking already existing customization

Tags: java, git, configuration, config, workflow

Similarly to [Git best practice for config files etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342886/git-best-practice-for-config-files-etc) - preferably using git - what is a best practice to release the updated default configurations (actually a bunch of files), without overriding the user's already customized ones?

The only idea that came to my mind is the following approach, using couple of branches:

```
master (releases only) --- 1.0 -- 2.0 ---------------- 3.0 --------- 4.0 -- "and so on" 
                            |      |                    |             |
custom                     1.1 -- 2.1 -- 2.2 -- 2.3 -- 3.1 -- 3.2 -- 4.1 --
```

merging the released default configurations onto the custom branch, trying to get new default properties without losing the customized ones, with least (auto) merge conflicts.

Sometimes the `ours` merge strategy - with `git merge -s ours master` - seems to minimize possible conflicts, but this is not always the case.

Is out there another possible approach, to better achieve my goal?

**NOTE** imagine that in practice custom branches may be a very large number and that the sketched merge procedure is achieved with a batch job (`bash` scripts with `git` commands). The aim is to minimize users intervention.

Answer (score 1):

We use template files like `config_template.ini`. After an update the user can `diff` their local `config.ini` with the current `config_template.ini`. If they only see differences in the values, then that is probably just a usual customization. If they see a new value in the template, they should come up with an apropriate value for their installation. And if the template is missing a value they have in their local config that means this value is no longer needed.