# How to determine windows home directory in a C macro?

Tags: c, windows

I have the following code snippet that stores a macro containing the configuration file path for an editor I am writing.

```
#ifdef _WIN32 
#define CONFIG_FILE_PATH /* windows path here */
#else
#define CONFIG_FILE_PATH "~/.stupid_editor_rc"
#endif
```

Is there a windows equivalent to `~` in Unix systems, or is there a way to fit a function that determines the Windows home directory in a C macro such as this one?

Comment: No, and `~` is a shell thing so it’d be somewhat unusual if that even worked for you on non-Windows without some [`expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) kind of step. A good question to ask (although this one doesn’t have ideal answers) is [how to obtain a cross-platform path for a configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486642/obtaining-cross-platform-path-for-config-file-c-c).

Comment: In windows there is `%userprofile%`. But it depends what you are doing with this thing, that is who is going to interpret it (like the shell, as mentioned).

Comment: This will pretty much only be used with the `fopen` function - would `%userprofile%` work there?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71671790/getting-userprofile-to-work-in-fopen-and-or-char-array-c

Comment: @vs07, no, I would not expect `%userprofile%` to work with `fopen()`.

Comment: [Per this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42700778/4756299): `WCHAR profilePath[MAX_PATH];
HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_PROFILE, NULL, 0, profilePath);`.  Then build the full path to the file you want from the contents of `profilePath`.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, simply call the `GetCurrentDirectory` API function? Is in the path to wherever the .exe is executed from.

Comment: @Lundin: The working directory and home directory (e.g. `C:\Users\You`) are different things.

Comment: @Ry- So `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` or something. My point is, just use an API function.

Comment: @Lundin: Well, yeah. Specifically, `SHGetFolderPathW`, as in the preceding comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a windows equivalent to `~` in Unix systems,

Not that I am aware of.

And that's probably the wrong question anyway.  The use of `~` that you're thinking about is a function of the shell, not the underlying OS.  The system itself does not perform tilde expansion any more on Unix than it does on Windows.

> or is there a way to fit a function that determines the Windows home directory in a C macro such as this one?

Supposing that you want the program to choose the configuration file of the user who is running it, as opposed to the one who built it, the approach you are attempting won't work on either Windows or Unix, but there are alternatives. (And even if you wanted the builder's config file, you would need to go about setting the macro's value differently.)

On Unix, one would probably construct the wanted path dynamically at runtime, based on the value of the `HOME` environment variable.  That can be read via the `getenv()` function, so something like this overall:

```
    const char config_name[] = ".stupid_editor_rc";
    const char *home_path = getenv("HOME");
    // check for and handle environment variable not defined ...

    char *config_path = malloc(strlen(home_path) + sizeof config_name + 1);
    // check for and handle handle allocation failure ...

    sprintf(config_path, "%s/%s", home_path, config_name);
    FILE *config_file = fopen(config_path);
    // check for and handle fopen failure ...

    free(config_path);
    // ...
```

You should be able to do similar in Windows by using the appropriate Windows environment variable(s).  There's not an exact equivalent, but `UserProfile` is pretty close.  If you don't have to deal with home directories on network shares then you probably don't need to worry about the difference.

Macro-izing that for automatic compile-time selection of the appropriate variable is left as an exercise.

Comment: In Windows, you could set up your own `HOME` environmental variable.

Comment: True, @WeatherVane, or the program could specify a bespoke environment variable by which the location of a personal config file could be conveyed.  But as a quality-of-implementation matter, I think it's preferable to have a working default that doesn't require special user action.

Comment: Thanks! Given that the proper solution is more complicated than I imagined, I'll probably leave it as a function that gets executed upon running the program